# ggplot missing labels in legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, label

I want to plot some data and then add a regression line and horizontal lines for the mean and mean +/- the standard deviation, each in a different colour. I have managed to do this but I can't get the legend right. It shows labels for the first two but says nothing about the three horizontal lines. How can I get the legend to have a label for each of these three lines too?

Another post mentioned show_guide = TRUE, but this didn't work for me. I've also been looking at the documentation for scale_colour_manual but that didn't help me.

My code is this:

```
p <- qplot(mpg, wt, data = mtcars, colour="1")
p <- p + geom_smooth(method='lm',aes(x=mpg,y=wt,colour="2"),formula=y~x)
p <- p + geom_hline(yintercept = mean(mtcars$wt), colour = "3")
p <- p + geom_hline(yintercept = mean(mtcars$wt) + sd(mtcars$wt), colour = "3",    linetype="dashed")
p <- p + geom_hline(yintercept = mean(mtcars$wt) - sd(mtcars$wt), colour = "3", linetype="dashed")      
p <- p + labs(colour="")    
p <- p + scale_colour_manual(values = c("red","blue", "green","green","green"),labels=c("Data","Regression","Mean","Mean + SD","Mean - SD"))
p <- p + guides(colour = guide_legend())
print(p)
```

Any help will be much appreciated,
cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is probably closer to what you want:

```
d <- data.frame(yint = c(mean(mtcars$wt) - sd(mtcars$wt),
                mean(mtcars$wt),
                mean(mtcars$wt) + sd(mtcars$wt)),
                grp = c('dashed','solid','dashed'))

p <- ggplot(data = mtcars,aes(mpg, wt)) + 
    geom_point(aes(color = "Data")) +
    geom_smooth(method='lm',aes(x=mpg,y=wt,color = "Regression"),formula=y~x) + 
    geom_hline(data = d,aes(yintercept = yint,linetype = grp,color = "Mean +/- SD")) + 
    scale_linetype_manual(values = c('dashed' = 'dashed','solid' = 'solid')) + 
    labs(color = "")
print(p)
```

As to the question about labeling each of the horizontal lines separately, my answer is that that doesn't belong in the legend at all. Those should be labeled with `geom_text()`:

```
d <- data.frame(yint = c(mean(mtcars$wt) - sd(mtcars$wt),
                         mean(mtcars$wt),
                         mean(mtcars$wt) + sd(mtcars$wt)),
                         grp = c('dashed','solid','dashed'),
                         lab = c('-SD','Mean','+SD'))

p <- ggplot(data = mtcars,aes(mpg, wt)) + 
    geom_point(aes(color = "Data")) +
    geom_smooth(method='lm',aes(x=mpg,y=wt,color = "Regression"),formula=y~x) + 
    geom_hline(data = d,aes(yintercept = yint,linetype = grp),color = "green") + 
    geom_text(data = d,aes(y = yint,label = lab),
              vjust = -0.5,hjust = 1,x = Inf,size = 3) +
    scale_linetype_manual(values = c('dashed' = 'dashed','solid' = 'solid')) + 
    labs(color = "")
print(p)
```

Comment: I'm afraid not. With your code the original data is not plotted and the legend only shows two labels. It is absolutely necessary that the original data is plotted and labeled in the legend in addition to the regression line and the mean and mean +/- SD lines.

Comment: @ermutarra See my edits (which I had assumed would be trivial changes, but I guess not). I was trying to guide you towards some better ggplot practices. Note that you should never, ever, be referring to columns directly like `mtcars[,n+1]` inside of `aes()`. That is very bad practice, and the non-standard evaluation will burn you eventually if you persist in doing that. Additionally, anytime you're adding multiple copies of the same geom, that's a sure sign that you're doing something wrong. ggplot is not designed to be used that way. (Just to be clear, I didn't down vote.)

Comment: That's much closer to what I need, thanks! but I still wonder whether you could show the five lines in the legend. Thanks for pointing out that my approach is bad practice, I'm only just starting and need to learn those things!

Comment: @ermutarra I edited again to add my thoughts on the last issue.

Comment: that's perfect! I didn't know it was possible to do that :) thanks a lot for all your help

Answer (score -1):

Joran's answer inspired me to make some changes and now I have managed to write some code that gives me the plot and legend I was looking for:

```
n <- ncol(mtcars)
mtcars[,n+1] <- mean(mtcars$wt)
mtcars[,n+2] <- mean(mtcars$wt) + sd(mtcars$wt)
mtcars[,n+3] <- mean(mtcars$wt) - sd(mtcars$wt)
p <- qplot(mpg,wt,data = mtcars, colour="1")
p <- p + geom_smooth(method='lm',aes(x=mpg,y=wt,colour="2"),formula=y~x)
p <- p + geom_line(aes(x=mpg,y=mtcars[,n+1],colour="3"))
p <- p + geom_line(aes(x=mpg,y=mtcars[,n+2],colour="4"),linetype="dashed")
p <- p + geom_line(aes(x=mpg,y=mtcars[,n+3],colour="5"),linetype="dashed")
p <- p + labs(colour="")    
p <- p + scale_colour_manual(values = c("red","blue",  "green","green","green"),labels=c("Data","Regression","Mean","Mean + SD","Mean - SD"))
p <- p + guides(colour = guide_legend())
print(p)
```